# ASIN List on Products API?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, amazon-mws

Morning,

I am trying to pass a list of Amazon ASIN's so i can process them using the MWS API.

```
 List<string> prodASINs = dc.aboProducts.Select(a => a.asin).ToList();
            var count = prodASINs.Count();
            //Loop through passing 10 at a time to AWS
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var prodASINToSend = prodASINs.Skip(i * 10).Take(10).ToList();
                //Send to AWS

                MarketplaceWebServiceProductsConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsConfig();
                config.ServiceURL = productsURL;

                MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient(appname, version, accesskeyID, secretkey, config);

                GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest request = new GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest();
                request.SellerId = merchantID;
                request.MarketplaceId = marketids[0];
                request.ItemCondition = condition;
                request.ASINList.ASIN = prodASINToSend;
```

However the `request.ASINList.ASIN = prodASINToSend;` is saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." However it is passing over the required `List<string>` prodASINToSend

Could anyone shed some light on this for em please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means you forgot to declare a new instance of a class before trying to use the class object.

In your case the ASINList will need to be declared as a new instance of the ASINList class.